# Having trouble accessing object data from JSON file in Gamemaker

Tags: json, object, types, accessor, game-maker

I'm having an issue accessing JSON data for my game. Basically, I'm trying to pull this data in to use as dialogue. Here's the (relevant) snippet of JSON code below:

```
{
     "actOne" : {
         "foxA" : {
             "gameStateA" : [
                 "Oh hi",
                 "So you must be the new fox in town",
                 "I'm Beatrice. Not Bea. Beatrice. what's your favorite color?"
                {
                     "optionA" : ["Red obvi", 0],
                     "optionB" : ["Black like my heart", 1],
                     "optionC" : ["Gray like my morals", 2]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code I'm using to access it in STEP:

```
currDialogue = jsonParsed.actOne[$ npcName][$ currGameState]
```

where currDialogue is an array (declared in Create) and is iterated through to draw text to the screen and jsonParsed is the parsed JSON string of course.
npcName and currGameState are both obj variables declared in Create as well and in this case, they are currently hardcoded to "foxA" and "gameStateA", respectively.

So, the above code doesn't work. I'm getting this error:

```
############################################################################################ERROR inaction number 1of  Step Event0for object obj_dialogue:

variable_struct_get argument 1 incorrect type (undefined) expecting a Number (YYGI32)at gml_Object_obj_dialogue_Step_0 (line 8) - currDialogue = jsonParsed.actOne[$ npcName][$ currGameState];############################################################################################gml_Object_obj_dialogue_Step_0 (line 8)
```

HOWEVER, what's really strange is that these lines of code DO work:

```
currDialogue = jsonParsed.actOne.foxA[$ currGameState]
```

and

```
currDialogue = jsonParsed.actOne.foxA.gameStateA
```

So I know for sure that I am accessing the JSON file correctly and when I use the . accessor it's working. However, I can't just hardcode it like this because those variables need to change depending on which NPC you're talking to, the game state, etc. Is there something wrong with my syntax in using the template string accessor [$ ]?

I am at a complete loss for why this isn't working so any help would be greatly appreciated. On MacOS btw. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try running the game in debug mode and inspect what the variables are when the error pops up - perhaps `npcName` or `currGameState` don't hold what you think they do (and note that both variables and struct keys are case-sensitive).

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I added both "npcName" and "currGameState" to the Watch variables but the value just reads "<fetching>" and never updates. Not quite sure what to make of that.
The error pops up at the very start of the game and I can't play any of it at all, so maybe that's why?

Comment: You can also use the Locals or Instance panel to look at the variables, or even move your mouse over them - Watch panel can have occasional oddities.

Comment: Do you have any documentation for Locals or Instance panel or could you direct me to where that is? I don't see those in the IDE.

Comment: By default they should appear in the Variables tab, but you can re-summon the window through Debugger➜Windows menu if you closed it ([manual](https://manual.yoyogames.com/index.htm?#t=IDE_Tools%252FThe_Debugger%252FWatches.htm))